# Frequency multiplier.

Tags: functions, fourier-series, laplace-transform, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

What's the name of the mathmatical operation on which a pure sine function, or a Fourier series has the frequency multiplied by a constant "a", for example? "a" is a positive, non-zero, real number.

$$\sin (2* \pi * f) \to \sin (a* 2* \pi * f)$$

Also, what's the laplace transform of such operation?

Two good examples would be: a [this pure sine wave video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqwFimG3X3w&ab_channel=SonicElectronix) from YouTube, played at 2x speed. Also, a 33RPM record being played on 45RPM turntable.

Comment: Replacing a function $f(x)\to f(ax)$ is often called a (horizontal) stretch or shrink in the context of algebra.

Comment: Does this name, "horizontal stretching/shrinking" apply to sine functions, therefore to Fourier series?

Comment: Yes, sine functions can also experience horizontal stretching or shrinking. It's not clear exactly what connection to the Fourier transform you're asking about. Logic (and/or a change of variables applied to the definition of a Fourier transform) suggests that if you double each frequency in the time domain, that you also double each frequency in the frequency domain.